# How to write click event for dynamic generated table's first td value in angular 6

Tags: angular6, angular7, angular8

I tried to write click event for table's tr td's value.I have generated one table and I have tableid.I want to show alert if I click first column td values.How we can do it?Any solution is there?

Please do not write any inline onclick events.i want to write inside `app.component.ts` file.

Example:

`app.component.html`:

```
<custom-table id="tableId">
     <table>
      <thead>
        <th>Company</th>
        <th>Contact</th>
        <th>Country</th>
      </thead>
      <tr>
        <td>123456</td> ---->If i click this i want to show alert with this value
        <td>Maria Anders</td>
        <td>Germany</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>253689</td>---->If i click this i want to show alert with this value
        <td
        <td>Francisco Chang</td>
        <td>Mexico</td>
      </tr> 
     </table>
<custom-table>
```

`app.component.ts`:

```
ngOnInit(){

???
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside `app.component.html`, add a template reference variable (using `#`) to your table element.

```
<table #mytable ... >
```

In `app.component.ts`, link the template reference variable with `ViewChild`, then install `click` listeners inside `ngAfterViewInit`.

```
import {Component, ViewChild, AfterViewInit, ElementRef} from '@angular/core';

export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {

    @ViewChild('mytable', {static: false}) tableRef: ElementRef<HTMLTableElement>;

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        for (let row of this.tableRef.nativeElement.rows) {
            const firstCell = row.childNodes.item(0);
            firstCell.addEventListener('click', () => alert(firstCell.textContent));      
        }
    }
```

[**StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9qx3xm)

**UPDATE**

If you want to make this work in Angular 6, 7 and 8, you can use `document.getElementById('tableId')` instead of using `ViewChild`.

Please have a look at this [**StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cic1cz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: I updated my answer with a solution that should work for Angular 6, 7, and 8

Comment: Updated my table structure..How can i found table tag inside custom table component?

Comment: and table data also coming from json